# C: corrupted iterator sending D-BUS signal

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dbus

I'm trying to make my program to lock and unlock the GNOME screen by sending corresponding D-BUS messages.
Executing that via dbus-send in shell the parameters look the following way.

Lock:

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock
```

Unlock:

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.SetActive boolean:false
```

And here's the C code:

```
void sendDbusSignal(char *action)
{
DBusMessage* msg;
DBusMessageIter args;
DBusConnection* conn;
DBusError err;
DBusPendingCall* pending;
int ret;
dbus_bool_t v_BOOLEAN;

dbus_error_init(&err);
if ( strcmp(action, "SetActive") == 0 ) {
    v_BOOLEAN = false;
    printf("running dbus_message_iter_append_basic");
    dbus_message_iter_append_basic(&args, DBUS_TYPE_BOOLEAN, &v_BOOLEAN);
}

// connect to the system bus and check for errors
conn = dbus_bus_get(DBUS_BUS_SESSION, &err);
if (dbus_error_is_set(&err)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Connection Error (%s)\n", err.message);
    dbus_error_free(&err);
}
if (conn == NULL) {
    exit(1);
}

// request our name on the bus
ret = dbus_bus_request_name(conn, "org.gnome.TypingMonitor", DBUS_NAME_FLAG_REPLACE_EXISTING , &err);
if (dbus_error_is_set(&err)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Name Error (%s)\n", err.message);
    dbus_error_free(&err);
}
if (DBUS_REQUEST_NAME_REPLY_PRIMARY_OWNER != ret) {
    exit(1);
}

msg = dbus_message_new_method_call("org.gnome.ScreenSaver", // target for the method call
                          "/org/gnome/ScreenSaver", // object to call on
                          "org.gnome.ScreenSaver", // interface to call on
                          action); // method name
dbus_message_iter_init_append(msg, &args);
// send message and get a handle for a reply
if (!dbus_connection_send_with_reply (conn, msg, &pending, -1)) { // -1 is default timeout
    fprintf(stderr, "Out Of Memory!\n");
    exit(1);
}
if (pending == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Pending Call Null\n");
    exit(1);
}
dbus_connection_flush(conn);

printf("Request Sent\n");

// free message
dbus_message_unref(msg);

// free the pending message handle
dbus_pending_call_unref(pending);
}

int main()
{
sendDbusSignal("Lock");
sleep(5);
sendDbusSignal("SetActive");
return 0;
}
```

And here's what happens when I kick it off:

1. "Lock" signal is getting sent successfully and screen is being locked
2. sleeps for 5 seconds
3. Executing sendDbusSignal("SetActive") throws "process 8905: dbus message iterator looks uninitialized or corrupted"

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: I suggest using [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) to see whether it spots what is going wrong.  The symptom sounds like you are trampling on uninitialized memory somewhere, or trampling out of bounds of allocated memory.  Valgrind can spot many (but not all) such abuses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't start using the iterator before you've initialized it: The `dbus_message_iter_init_append()` call needs to happen before appending anything to it.

By the way, if you're just trying to find an easy way to use D-Bus from C I'd really suggest taking a look at GDBus instead of using the low-level libdbus API: It really is a lot less painful.

Comment: Thanks! I just moved boolean type appending part after `dbus_message_iter_init_append(msg, &args);` line, and it worked!